# how to make text below my heading?

Tags: html, css, header, position, alignment

I want to put a heading above my 3 images saying "Staff Picks". I dont understand why but for some reason it goes underneath the heading instead of below. Please help i know its basic but usually it sinks below.

body HTML

```
<div class = "container_index">
<img src = "eag.jpg" width = "30%">
<img src = "thewall.jpg" width = "30%">
<img src = "em.jpg" width = "30%">
</div>
```

CSS

```
h3 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 2%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/248m822a

Comment: "...it goes underneath the heading instead of below". Those mean the same thing. Also, neither h3 nor header are present in your HTML, so it would be impossible to tell what your mistake is. It might help if you post a jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Ill try and make a js fiddle now

Comment: there is a header tag in html by the way i just didnt put it in

Comment: If you edit your code to include all of your HTML, I can better help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/248m822a/

Comment: I havent uploaded the images but it shouldnt matter if it does let me know

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` from your header and see if that fixes it. By positioning the header absolutely it is taken out of the flow of the document which can lead to overlapping.

Alternatively you could give your `h3` element some padding/margin to compensate for the overlap... or your header, depending on the situation.

Comment: Thanks good idea. That made the header alot smaller and took the nav bar out of the header. If you understand what i mean. Although the h3 has moved down abit its still over lapping a little.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/248m822a/1/
I gave the body tag some top padding.

Comment: My images arent in jsfiddle so you wont understand but i want the heading the same width of the images and to sit directly above the middle image. I have the width sorted theyre both 30% but i cant get it to sit right above the middle image

Comment: @user3774020 You're right, I'm not sure what you are aiming for, but it might help to move the `<h3>` element inside of the container with the 3 images, and then giving it the 30% width... does this get you closer? https://jsfiddle.net/248m822a/7/

Answer (score 0):

perhaps take the hardcoded width out and try this ?

```
.container_index{
    margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 10px
  }
.container_index img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 30%;
}

.container_index img:hover {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The images aren't fully centered on the page. You can fix this by add another div around the group of images inside container_index and give it:

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

Then remove the display property from .container_index img and move the widths from the html to .container_index img. Here is an example of what it would look like: https://jsfiddle.net/ryp9d1dj/ (Forked from pschueller's fix to the overlapping h1 and nav. Different images added since the fix doesn't display correctly with the broken image icons.)